# Passing data from javascript to PHP via POST not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to send an array, populated using javascript on client-side, to a php file in the backend.

**MAIN.JS**

```
    var list = iterateItems();
  _ajax("https://127.0.0.1/prog1/final/class/ticket.php", list)
  .done(function(list){});
  });
  function _ajax(url,data) {
    var ajax = $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      datatype : "string",
      url : url,
      data : data
    })
    return ajax;
  }
  
  
  function iterateItems() {
    // array is an array populated in this function, returned to be sent to ticket.php
    return JSON.stringify( array );
  };
```

**TICKET.PHP**

```
<?php
   var_dump(json_decode($_POST['list']));
?>
```

And executing this, I'm getting this result:

```
Notice: Undefined index: list in D:\127.0.0.1/prog1/final/class/ticket.php on line 2
NULL
```

Im not understanding why im getting an undefined index.
I tried googling this, but most responses seem to point in the direction of using some kind of HTTPS method, which is what I'm trying to achieve via POST.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you sent to the PHP backend?

Comment: I've tried with an array of JSONs, such as
` [{"id": 1,"name": "product"},{"id": 2, "name": "product2"}] `

And the stringified version
` "[{\"id\": 1,\n \"name\": \"product\"},\n{\"id\": 2,\n \"name\": \"product2\"}]"`
Sorry for multiple edits, having trouble with formatting

Comment: `$_POST['lista']` is the `a` a typo? `Undefined index: list`

Comment: Yes, Im sorry. Code is in Spanish originally, as Im a spanish speaker, and it slipped. Will edit now. Can assure that it is consistent with the code

Comment: You might need to set the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something about the`_ajax` call, but I don’t see `list` as a variable name to be sent. You’re sending the value of the javascript variable "list" (`iterateItems()`), but not the variable name. Ergo, index “list” is undefined. To debug, all you need to do is `print_r($_POST)` and you’ll (hopefully) see your data, probably with no need to json_decode()

Answer (score 0):

The 'list' undefined issue might be due to the structure of the JSON array you pass.

Try the below code and check if it works. If not let's check further :)

```js
    var list = {'list': iterateItems()};
  _ajax("https://127.0.0.1/prog1/final/class/ticket.php", list)
  .done(function(list){});
  });
  function _ajax(url,data) {
    var ajax = $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      datatype : "json",
      url : url,
      data : data
    })
    return ajax;
  }
  
  
  function iterateItems() {
    // array is an array populated in this function, returned to be sent to ticket.php
    return JSON.stringify( array );
  };
```

Your PHP Code:

```
<?php

   var_dump(json_decode($_POST['list']));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't parse JSON parameters automatically. `$_POST` will only be filled in from a URL-encoded string or a FormData object.

`$.ajax` will URL-encode an array automatically for you.

```
_ajax("https://127.0.0.1/prog1/final/class/ticket.php", array)
  .done(function(list) {});

function _ajax(url, data) {
  var ajax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "string",
    url: url,
    data: {list: data}
  })
  return ajax;
}
```

In PHP you then don't need to call `json_decode()`. The value of `$_POST['list']` will be the array.